# Unlock tenant administrator

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I run a `5.2.0.2` WSO2 Identity Server.

I have created a tenant (let's say `my.tenant`), and I somehow managed to lock the admin account of that tenant. How can I unlock it?

I know how to unlock a normal account by using the UI with the admin account of the user's tenant, but I fail to see how to unlock the admin itself.

What I tried:

- Using the UI with the super admin account (`admin@carbon.super`), I don't seem to be able to manage users from other tenants (only those from tenant `carbon.super`).
- The WSDL for the UserIdentityManagement Admin Service has the following operation:

  ```
      <xs:element name="unlockUserAccount">
          <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="userName" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="notificationType" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
              </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
  ```

... but it doesn't seem to take a "tenant" argument, so I guess if I connect to this service using `admin@carbon.super` I won't be able to act on `admin@my.tenant`.

- Trying to use UserIdentityManagement Admin Service with account `admin@my.tenant` fails because of the lock.

Comment: Do you have the liberty to change configs and restart the server etc.?

Comment: @farasath yes I do

Answer (score 0):

Go to WSO2_HOME/repository/conf/identity/identity-mgt.properties

Set the below property to 'false',

```
Authentication.Policy.Enable=false
```

Then use UserIdentityManagement Admin Service with account admin@my.tenant to unlock the user.

Alternatively, you can log in as admin@my.tenant (once you enable the above property account check lock on login will be disabled) and change the account lock claims using the user profile.